# How to move C:\Users to E:\Users in Win7

Tags: user-profile, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to move c:\users to d:\users under vista/W7](https://serverfault.com/questions/8187/whats-the-best-way-to-move-c-users-to-d-users-under-vista-w7)

I've googled this and found several multi-step/regedit ways of moving the Users' directory.  Is there not a simple way (like in WinXP) to move them?  Am I really going to have to muck around in the registry to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also multi-step, but no registry involved:

- [What's the best way to move c:\users to d:\users under vista/W7](https://serverfault.com/questions/8187/whats-the-best-way-to-move-c-users-to-d-users-under-vista-w7)

I did not try it, but it has only 5 steps, one of which is "verify everything has been copied". Take a look at the second answer, too.

Given the troubles with the system folders/files, I seem to prefer to make a huge C:\ and just forget about this. It's just easier then fiddling around and trying to patch the other issues that arise from doing it.