# How to use robocopy to move Users folder from partition c to d on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, users, robocopy

I just tried to copy my `Users` folder from partition `C` to partition `D` [using the method mentioned in this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/8187/whats-the-best-way-to-move-c-users-to-d-users-under-vista-w7).

Unfortunately I encountered two problems:

1. When using the command `robocopy c:\Users d:\Users /mir /xj /copyall`, robocopy says that it can't find the file `C:\Users\`, although it exists.
2. When using the command `robocopy x:\Users d:\Users /mir /xj /copyall`, robocopy says that it cannot find the path `d:\Users\Administrator\Application Data`, `error code <0x00000003>`.

I started the command line mode of my Windows 7 installation disk (repair mode).

Does anybody know what the reasons for these errors might be?

Answer (score 1):

Using sysprep is the easiest way to create user profiles in a different location.

All the other, unofficial ways, such as messing around with junctions and copying or moving files around, gave me a `The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded.` profile error.

- Windows 8: [How to Relocate User Profiles to another Partition or Disk in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4275-user-profiles-relocate-another-partition-disk.html)
- Windows 7: [How to Create User Accounts on another Partition or Disk During Windows 7 Installation](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/124198-user-profiles-create-move-during-windows-7-installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe repair mode labels your installation drive as X, not C. It could be any letter though.

Take a look through this post:
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-7-recovery-environment-command-prompt/

It'll go over the nuances of the recovery environment with you, such as drive letters and other specifics.

Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Thank you for this hint. It seems as if in the repair mode the device labels are being incremented: c->d, d->e. I wasn't aware of this fact. So that I got working. Yet another problem remains: After copying everything to the next device, making a symbolic link and restarting the Computer it cannot find the account specific data of any activated users any more. And this happens although the link points exactly to the right folder (I checked it after Windows had booted again).

Comment: Okay, so basically you're moving a User's profile during repair mode to a different drive, right? If that is accurate, follow this link. http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/05/how-to-change-user-profile-default-location-in-windows-7/ - There are registry elements that need to be modified as well for this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Everyone seems to be too occupied trying to find a solution of copying files and folders (Including links). Well, sorry to disappoint but as of this writing, I don't think there is a copy utility that does this well. Not Xcopy, not Robocopy, not any 3rd party software that I know of. However, the correct mindset should be imaging these files and folders instead of copying. How about using DISM.exe or ImageX.exe to /CAPTURE these folders to a WIM then re-/APPLY-ying them to the target? I've found this to be the best solution as its fast, and does its job efficiently (Preserving everything from Links, Permissions, System and Hidden files/directories).

```
ImageX /CAPTURE C:\USERS D:\TMP\USERS.WIM
ImageX /APPLY D:\TMP\USERS.WIM 1 E:\MYUSERS\USERS
```

Then just create links to the root of the USERS directory to point to the new location. All done and happy.